# Does flatc validate Required fields of Flatbuffer schema of the given JSON?

Tags: python, c++, json, protocol-buffers, flatbuffers

I am trying to use Flatbuffers, and I can validate my JSON response agains the Flatbuffer schema using flatc. it seems like flatc doesn't check if Required fields exist or not? am I missing something or Does flatc not validate Required fields of Flatbuffer schema of the given JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like indeed it fails to verify required fields are present. This would be easy to add however, you should file an issue (or a PR) on github.

Comment: you mentioned it's easy to add the feature. how would I go about doing that myself?

Comment: That's assuming you know C++. You'd find the spot in the parser where it parses a table (`Parser::ParseTable` in `idl_parser.cpp`), then you'd go thru all fields, and for any required one, test a value has been set for it.